# Jest testing redux connected component gives error " please ensure the component is wrapped in a <Provider>"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, jestjs, automated-tests

I am trying to test using jest a component in my react app that needs redux's `useDispatch()`. I get the error

> could not find react-redux context value; please ensure the component is wrapped in a

I don't get such error on any other component other than the one which uses redux's `useDispatch()`.

**Here is the error**

It shows part of the component

```
  could not find react-redux context value; please ensure the component is wrapped in a <Provider>

  10 |   //props so I can re-use it on homepage and in user page.
  11 |   const [query, setQuery] = useState('')
> 12 |   const dispatch = useDispatch()
     |                    ^
  13 | 
  14 |   const handleCriterionChange = () => {
  15 |     const value = document.getElementById("searchCriteria").value;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are probably not rendering the tested component in a Provider, but you wrap your whole app in one, so the dispatch is passed down from that. You need to wrap that component additionally in your test.

```
// In your test
render(<Providers store={YOUR STORE}>YOUR COMPONENT</Provider>)
```

This will let the tested component to access the dispatch.

You could also generate a helper which you pass the component you want to test to wrap it in a provider automatically:

```
function renderWithWrapper = children => <Providers store={YOUR STORE}>{children}</Provider>
```

Comment: Isn't there a better way to render components in tests when using redux? Do I really have to wrap each and every component? I could not come across any solution to this on the internet although redux is used quite commonly. I might be missing something.

Comment: I would abstract it away by writing a new render function where you pass the component to and just use it instead of the normal render function of the lib

Comment: Thanks Domino987 for your feedback. I got another problem though. I wrapped the component as per above but now it gives another error about all the React and hook stuff like the following: 

useHref() may be used only in the context of a <Router> component.

My application fully works, but tests crash. Do you have any idea about it?

Comment: Same thing. You need to wrap the test components in the router context just as the redux context via a provider. I hope you extracted the new render function since now you can simply add a router provideraround the redux test provider